# Which oracle version compatible with visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can anybody suggest which version of oracle database will be more compatible 
while working with an asp.net application?

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript or a particular version of C#? I'd expect any recent version of Oracle - along with a corresponding version of driver code - to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm) you'll need

- Oracle Database 9.2 or later or Oracle Database XE
- Oracle 11g Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio version 11.1.0.6.20 or later from OTN

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18692/Instant-Oracle-Using-C) is another version which IMHO provides nice details